# Javascript - Hide a div with a reset button

Tags: javascript, reset

I need a UL, containing the search results (ul.job_listings) to hide after a reset button is pressed.
So far a reset has been set up to reset the search form:

```
$( '.job_filters' ).on( 'click', '.reset', function () {
        var target = $( this ).closest( 'div.job_listings' );
        var form = $( this ).closest( 'form' );

        form.find( ':input[name="search_keywords"], :input[name="search_location"], .job-manager-filter' ).not(':input[type="hidden"]').val( '' ).trigger( 'chosen:updated' );
        form.find( ':input[name^="search_categories"]' ).not(':input[type="hidden"]').val( 0 ).trigger( 'chosen:updated' );
        $( ':input[name="filter_job_type[]"]', form ).not(':input[type="hidden"]').attr( 'checked', 'checked' );

        target.triggerHandler( 'reset' );
        target.triggerHandler( 'update_results', [ 1, false ] );
        job_manager_store_state( target, 1 );

        return false;
    } );
```

How would I add to it to also hide the results div?

Thanks for any help,
Liz.

Comment: var $jobListings = $( this ).closest( 'ul.job_listings' );
  $($jobListings).hide();

Comment: Yeah, it's really unclear what is supposed to be hidden. Two mentions of a `div` being hidden, one mention of a `ul`. In any case, take whatever element you want to hide and call `.hide` on it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to be using jQuery, it you could just add

```
target.hide();
```

before the `return` statement.

---

edit - see comments above :-)

Comment: No need for the `$(...)`. (See my comment above.)